# How to create a makeover application in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wanted to create a application like virtual makeover.Need to change the color of the skin and applying color for eyes. please guide me how to start on this.

Comment: This question is extremely vague. What have you tried so far? Can you be more specific on where you are stuck?

Comment: @MichaelW I just want to clarify before i start the app. Can you please tell me the few initial steps.So far i just loaded the external image.I don't know how to proceed to next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of the [`ColorTransform`](http://asgamer.com/2011/changing-colors-with-colortransform-in-as3-code) property. To check the correct color (or color range) you need to switch, you have to do a few calculations. Calculate where the face is in the picture. Calculate where the eyes are. Then calculate what the color is, and then change the color (with an offset to make sure the whole eye is colored).

Same goes for the skin.